# Change Date Format in Article Editing page on Publishing tab

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, date

I would like to change the date format of the following fields Article Editing page on Publishing tab):

```
Start Publishing
Finish Publishing
Created Date
Modified Date
```

The format is by default `Y-m-d H:i:s` and I would like to set it to `d-F-Y H:i:s`!
[Print Screen of the field where I want to change the date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqrKm.png)

In language manager I have been on the override tab then
 - Select the filter `English (USA) - administrator` 
 - Search for the constant `DATE_FORMAT_LC2` 
 - Override the date format in the "text" field by entering `d-F-Y H:i:s`

but without succes. My webiste is under Joomla 3.3.1

Answer (score 4):

Go to Extension Manager -> Language Manager. Select Overrides.

Select the Language for which you want to set an override and change the date format. Add a new override.

Select the Constant option (Search for the constant DATE_FORMAT_LC2/LC3/LC4). Modify its value and save the changes. Just remove the text and type in the format you'd like.

For example, if you want the date to display January 01, 2013, you would use : `F j, Y`

Refresh the page. The date format was changed.

---

Also, here is a list of common date format lettering which is used in Joomla:

**l** (lowercase 'L')     A full textual representation of the day of the week

**d**     Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros

**M**     A short textual representation of a month, three letters

**m**     Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros

**F**     A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March

**Y**     A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits

**H**     24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros

**i**     Minutes with leading zeros

Comment: I've already tried that but it isn't working. I have added a print screen so that you can see the field where I want to changet the date format. The current date format doesn't fit into any of the DATE_FORMAT_LC2/LC3/LC4 string

Comment: Make sure that you select the appropriate language (e.g., en-GB) and the location (Site or Admin - in your case Admin). Also, make sure that the string you enter as a CONSTANT is correct. Also you may need to clear the cache. Failing that I'm not sure!

Comment: Thanks @johnny_s for your help! I went over the whole process again but couldn't find my mistake. What suprises my is that the "start publishing" field date format is 2014-02-09 19:45:27 which is int the Y-m-d H:i:s Format. I can't find this format in any of the Joomla constant DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: That's strange. You have cleared the cache? What about if you change the admin template, does the problem still persist? You could also open the theme language file and check if the information regarding date formats is specified there. You can find the theme language file in the language\en-GB folder of your Joomla installation. It is called en-GB.tpl_themeXXXX.ini, where XXXX is the theme number. I would advise to use the Joomla override in the admin area though if possible.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I could make the override works on the article manager page where DATE_FORMAT_LC4 is used. But I still can't make in work for the Start Publishing /Finish Publishing / Created Date / Modified Date fields. I have tried with all the DATE_FORMAT format but none of them fit the 2014-02-09 19:45:27 format that is displayed in the cited fields.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion about template change and language override file?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry I forgot to mention that. It's still not working with the other admin template. I have been in the administrator\language\en-GB folder to have a look at the ini file (my admin template is isis) but there isn't anything related to date format in those files.

Comment: It's normally not this difficult, if you are certain you have changed extensions > language manager > overrides > filter > admin > new override > search for constant > DATE_FORMAT_LC2/LC3/LC4 etc > set 'for both locations' (http://www.jevents.net/images/stories/langoverride_plugin_override.png) > save & close. Clear site cache, browser cache, logout/in. You could manually  add a language override in administrator > language > overrides folder.